# Cheapest can problem

Tags: calculus, geometry, derivatives

A cylindrical can which must hold 1000 mL is set to be designed so the least amount of material is necessary to make the can.

1. What should the radius be?
2. What is the height of the can?
3. What is the minimum surface area?

I'm not really sure how or where to start...please help!

Thanks,
Bill

Answer (score 4):

The surface area $A$ of a cylinder is given by:

$$A = 2\pi r^2 + h\times 2\pi r\tag{1}$$

Where $r$ is the radius of the cylinder, and $h$ is its height.

Volume, V, is given by

$$V = \pi r^2 \times h = 1000\tag{2}$$

We want to minimize surface area that yields a can of volume $1000$. That will minimize the cost of the material to build the can.

Express height $h$ as a function of $r$, using equation $(2)$,

$$ h=\frac{1000}{\pi r^2} \tag{3}$$

...Then substitute this expression for $h$ into the formula of $(1)$. This will give us surface area $A$ as a function of one variable, $r$:

$$ A(r) = 2\pi r^2 + 2\pi r \left(\frac{1000}{\pi r^2}\right) = 2\pi r^2 + \frac{2000}{r}\tag{A(r)}$$

We can find the value of $r$ by finding where $A(r)' = 0$:

So take the derivative of this last equation with respect to $r$, set $A'(r)$ equal to $0$ to solve for the only possible minimal value of $r$:

$$A(r)' = 4\pi r - \frac{2000}{r^2}$$

$$A(r)' = 0 \iff 4\pi r - \frac{2000}{r^2} = 0 \iff 4\pi r^3 - 2000 = 0 $$
$$\iff r^3 = \frac{2000}{4\pi} \iff r = \sqrt[\large 3]{\frac{2000}{4\pi}} \iff r = \sqrt[\large 3]{\frac{500}{pi}}$$

N.B. To confirm that $r = \sqrt[3]{\frac{500}{\pi}}$ gives the minimum surface area $(1)$, evaluate $A(r)$ at $r\lt \sqrt[3]{\frac{500}{\pi}}$, and $r >  \sqrt[\large 3]{\frac{500}{\pi}}$. We want to ensure that those values are greater than $A(\sqrt[\large 3]{\frac{500}{\pi}})$. *Then you know for sure* that $r = \sqrt[\large 3]{\frac{500}{\pi}}$ will indeed give the ***minimum*** surface area.

Now we solve for $h$ by substituting $r = \sqrt[\large 3]{\frac{500}{\pi}}$ into our equation for height given by $(3)$.

Then compute $A$ as given in $(1)$ using these values of $r$, $h$.

---

If you'd like to check your computations:

$$r = \sqrt[\large 3]{\frac {500}{\pi}}\approx 5.419$$

$$ h=\frac{1000}{\pi r^2} = \frac{1000}{\pi^{1/3}500^{2/3}}\approx 10.84$$

$$ A_{\text{minimum}} = 2\pi r^2 + h\times 2\pi r = 2\pi r(r + h) \approx 544.401$$

Comment: Very nice explanation and guidance. +1

Comment: It looks to me like you obtained the correct values, Bill. Good work!

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Let $r=$ the radius of the cylinder and $h$ = the height of the can.

Then an equation for the surface area is:
$$
SA=2\pi r^2 + 2\pi r h
$$

We also have a constraint on the volume:
$$V=\pi r^2h=1000
$$

We can minimize the $SA$ equation by taking the derivative, setting it equal to 0, and then using the Volume equation as a constraint. This will build the cheapest can.

Continuing on, we have:

$$
h=\frac{1000}{\pi r^2}\\
SA=2\pi r^2 + 2\pi r \left(\frac{1000}{\pi r^2}\right)=2\pi r^2 + \frac{2000}{r}
$$

Now, take the derivative of this last equation with respect to $r$, set the result equal to $0$ and solve for the minimal value of $r$:

$$
SA(r)'=4\pi r -\frac{2000}{r^2}=0
$$

Comment: What do you mean by constraint?

Comment: We can differentiate the $SA$ equation and set it equal to 0, but then we will have two unknowns and one equation. But we can use the $\pi r^2 h=1000$ equation too. So then we have two equations and two unknowns.

Comment: Sorry but I'm totally confused.  I'm in 8th grade and this is a brain teaser homework problem for us.  Please help direct me a little more.  Thx

Comment: What do you mean by take the derivative and setting it equal to zero?

Comment: Do you have any experience in Calculus?

Comment: No I'm taking Algebra II.

Comment: zach, your work is incorrect. $h$ is a function of $r$, and so must be differentiated with respect to $r$, if you proceed in the order you proceeded.

Comment: @amWhy, Thank you for pointing that out. I've edited the solution.

Comment: @Bill, if you solve the last equation for $r$, you'll have the minimum radius. Take that radius and plug it in to the volume equation, and you can easily solve for the height.

Comment: I'm struggling with taking the derivative of the last equation before I solve for r.  Please help.

Comment: I've taken it for you up there. Think of $\frac{2000}{r}$ as $2000r^{-1}$.

Comment: I got r= 5.42, h = 10.84, SA= 553.46

Comment: Do those answers look correct?  Thx

Comment: That's what I get. Nice job!

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks so much Zachary!